# Trying to return KeyValue Pair

Tags: c#

Sorry here is the complete code..... I want to pass back the fullname and abbreviation

public static Dictionary> CountryStates { get; set; }

```
    public CustomerUpdateDemographics()
    {
        if (CountryStates == null)
        {
            using (var service = new IQPWebServiceClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, erros) => { return true; };
                service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
                service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
                var response = service.GetCountryStates();

                if (response.ReturnStatus.StatusCode == 0)
                {
                    CountryStates = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
                    foreach (var countryState in response.CountryStates)
                    {

                        if (!CountryStates.ContainsKey(countryState.CountryCode))
                            CountryStates.Add(countryState.CountryCode, new List<string>());
                       CountryStates[countryState.CountryCode].Add(countryState.StateCode);

                    }

                }

           }
```

Comment: What do you want as result? The code you've posted is misleading. Also, there is no _"KeyValuePair as list"_ since it's a single object.

Comment: The question is kind of unclear to me.

Answer (score 4):

Are you wanting to return two strings from the function then?

`KeyValuePair<string, string>` would be a suitable type.

Answer (score 2):

ToList ?

```
return CountryStates.ToList();
```